# How to generate random numbers as object of arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to generate random numbers between 1 - 100 in the format. Not sure how to go about this..

```
random_object = {
     "01": [23, 54]
     "02": [37, 94]
     "03": [47, 92]
     .
     .
     "10": [93, 73]
    }
```

The numbers with a leading zero would be the object keys from (01 to 10).
[23, 54] should be randomly generated numbers from 0 to 100.

[image]

I get the `math.floor` generating random numbers. not just sure how to wrap all that into an object

Comment: You can generate a random number between 1 and 100 using `(Math.random() * 99) + 1`. (The +1 is required since it can be 0)

Comment: @thepieterdc technically `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1`

Comment: You'll just need to generate the numbers, add them to a new object, and append them to the array of random objects.

Comment: OP, what have you tried so far? What are you stuck on? Generating object keys? Generating random numbers?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee  random(), returns numbers from 0-1(with 0 been inclusive)..  So in theory you could get 0..

Answer (score 2):

You can loop 10 times, and use `String#padStart` to create the object keys. The values can be generated using `Math#random`.

```js
const random_object = {};

function random() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  const key = i.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  random_object[key] = [random(), random()];
}

console.log(random_object);
```